# Java equivalent of ntohll function

Tags: java, c++, type-conversion, endianness

Is there an equivalent of `ntohll` C++ function in Java?

The reference of `ntohll` can be found here: [ntohll function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj710202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The thing is I need to convert a 64 bits long from TCP/IP network order to little endian long.

Comment: maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895131/porting-c-code-need-help-with-bitwise-operation-and-pointer-syntax

Comment: @Maxbester why do you need the function? as in java you do not need to concern about network byte order.

Comment: apache commons `EndianUtils`

Comment: Java doesn't have an unsigned 64 bit integer type... what exactly do you need to use it for?

Comment: i think you have to reserse byte by byte. lets say 11101111 10011001 ->11110111 10011001

Comment: @Daniele I've tried to mask and shift the value but it didn't work.
@user3200809 I need to read a file writen by a C++ program.
@Mustafa I've tried this library a little but didn't manage to do it. Any example?
@Elliott Yes what about working with `BigInteger`?

Comment: @user3200809 reversing bit like this change the sign of the number. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Maxbester yes it will change the sign.

Comment: @Maxbester do you want to convert a binary file written in big indian format to little indian format right? you dont have to be concern using which language you have written your file. clarify my

Comment: @user3200809 Yes I have to read a binary file written by a C++ program. It contains Ethernet frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

java equivalent function of ntohll is: long is equivalent of 64 bit

```
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.ByteOrder;

   public long ntohll(long convert)
    {
            ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);  
            bbuf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);  
            bbuf.putLong(convert);  
            bbuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);  
            return bbuf.getLong(0); 
    }
```

Comment: This is equivalent to Zac Howland's answer below, but his version is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses network byte order already, so there is no need to convert them (which is why these functions do not exist in Java).

**Update**

Since you are reading a file that is in little endian bit patterns, you have to write your own (or use a library) if you are using JDK < 1.5.  If you are using JDK 1.5 or higher, you can use the `reverseBytes` method for the integer objects:

```
long data = Long.reverseBytes(some_data);
```

Comment: See my comment to user3200809, I need to read a file written by a C++ program and the conversion has not been done by the C++ program.